# Java Yourkit Profiler showing 5K+ char[] objects not getting garbage Collected, how can I tell what class is the culprit?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, profiling, eclipse-rcp

I have an RCP application and there is a slow memory leak and I recently started using YourKit Profiler which seems to be the best app out there for this. The question I have, is I see that over 20% of my objects char[] arrays and what I want to figure out is what class/method in my app is created all these instances as they do not seem to getting garbage collected. I am connected to a messaging server and consuming probably 500 text messages a second, but I am having a tough time using Yourkit to find the gradual memory leak. Thanks for any help.

Comment: http://www.yourkit.com/docs/demo/JavaMemoryLeak/JavaMemoryLeak.htm

Comment: Thanks for the link, I found out that 76% of my objects in memory are "unreachable from GC roots, but not yet collected" does that in other words mean a memory link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a YourKit developer, I can recommend to record object allocations as it's described here http://www.yourkit.com/docs/11/help/allocations.jsp

After that you'll see the places where each particular object was created. Please note, that allocation recording adds (sometime significant) profiling overhead.